# Print For /IF result to panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my Problem, i have this code:

```
for i, row in df_all.iterrows():
   mylist = (row.euclidian_distance)
   euclid_data.append(mylist)
   mylist1 = (row.day_night)
   day_night_data.append(mylist1)

    if (len(euclid_data)== 120):
        xbar = np.mean(euclid_data)
        dn = np.mean(day_night_data) 

        if(dn <= 0.5 and xbar >= day_thresh):
            euclid_track.append(0.0)
        elif (dn > 0.5 and xbar >= night_thresh):
            euclid_track.append(0.0)
        else:
            euclid_track.append(xbar)
            
        means.append(np.mean(euclid_data))

        if(len(euclid_track) >= 3 and sum(euclid_track[len(euclid_track)-3:]) == 0):
    
            print(row)         
            warn.append(i)

        if(len(warn)>=100):
           break
```

And my result is from **print(row)**:

[image: Result for code]

How do i get the result in pandas dataframe to look like this:

| id | date_time | euclidian_distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA00-0190148 | 2023-10-27 19:23:26 | 82.36223 |

and so forth...Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your data `df_all` as text instead of print

Comment: @SurajShourie how do I do that? And will that produce a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @user7446890 It won't solve your problem, it's just the preferred way to post code and results. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Format field

##### Create new row from copy with formats

```py
row_copy = row.copy()

# Datetime field
formatted_datetime = row_copy['date_time'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
row_copy['date_time'] = formatted_datetime

print(row_copy)
```

### Create new dataframe with the filtered data

If you want to save the filtered row, you can create a new dataframe only with those rows.
Example:

```py
# [...]
    if(len(euclid_track) >= 3 and sum(euclid_track[len(euclid_track)-3:]) == 0):
        filtered_rows.append(row)

filtered_df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_rows)
```

Or create new dataframe from python dictionary or python arrays:

```py
data = {'id': ['AA00-0190148', 'AA00-0190149', ...],
        'data_time': [2023-10-27 19:23:26, 2023-10-27 19:23:26, ...],
        'euclidian_distance': [82.36223, 91.32223, ...]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

### Show dataframe in console

If you want to show a table in the console, you can use [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/), this library shows a table in printable format.
You can tabulate a dataframe or a simple Python arrays

Example code:

```py
# Example with dataframe

import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, ...)

print(tabulate(dataframe, headers, tablefmt="grid"))

+--------+-------+
| item   |   qty |
+========+=======+
| spam   |    42 |
+--------+-------+
| eggs   |   451 |
+--------+-------+
| bacon  |     0 |
+--------+-------+

# Example with python arrays

print(tabulate([["Name","Age"],["Alice",24],["Bob",19]], headers="firstrow"))

Name      Age
------  -----
Alice      24
Bob        19
```

Another way is to show the head with `print(dataframe.head(n))` (n => number of rows) if you add columns with **euclidian_distance**.

Comment: @user7446890 I added a part for creating a filtered dataframe